# PHP sessions login system logs in but lands on a blank screen

Tags: php, session

I am struggling with this login system. What I am trying to accomplish is an admin area, platinum area and a gold area. When the script is run it logs in the user but it lands on a white screen. Using my browser's back button I can then get to the index and select the url I am trying to access and I am logged in. When I log out sometimes I can still access the pages but the session is lost as it should be. I should be directed to logon again but I am not.

The script below I named admincontrol.php

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['auth'] = "OKAY";

 //error_reporting(E_ALL);


 if (isset($_POST['username'])) 
    { $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : $_SESSION['username'];}


  $level = (isset($_POST['level']) ? $_POST['level'] : (isset($_SESSION['level']) ? $_SESSION['level'] : 'nolevel'));


  $pwd = (isset($_POST['pwd']) ? $_POST['pwd'] : (isset($_SESSION['pwd']) ? $_SESSION['pwd'] : 'nopwd'));


  if(empty($username)) {
 ?>

<!doctype html>
  <head>
   <title> Please Log In for Access</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
     content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  </head>
 <body>
  <div align="center">

    <img src="../images/alls.gif">

    <h1 align="center"> <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Login Required 
    </font></h1>
    <p align="center"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">You must log into access this area of the site. <br />
    </font></p></div>

 <div align="center">
  <form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"> 
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">User ID: 
    <input type="text" name="username" size="8" />
    <br />
  Password: 
  <input type="password" name="pwd" SIZE="8" />
  <br />
  <br />Select your title from the drop down
   <select name="level">
     <option value="1">Platinum</option>
     <option value="2">Gold</option>
     <option value="0">Admin</option>
  </select>
 <br /><br />
 <br /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
 </p>
  </font></form></div>
 </body>
 </html>
 <?php exit; 
 }
 $pwd = md5($pwd);
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 $_SESSION['pwd'] = $pwd;
 $_SESSION['level'] = $level;// 0 = Admin, 1 = institutional subscriber, 2 = individual subscriber

 include_once 'db.php';

  //allows user to access specific page only!
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$pwd' AND level = '$level'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);


 if (!$result) {
 error('A database error occurred while checking your '.
    'login details.\\nIf this error persists, please '.
    'contact me@my.com. ');

 }

 if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
 unset($_SESSION['username']);
 unset($_SESSION['pwd']);
 unset($_SESSION['level']);


 ?>
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">
 body{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
 </style>
 <title>Access Denied Admin</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 </head>
 <center>
 <body>
 <h1> Access Denied </h1>
 <p>Your user ID or password or Title are incorrect, or you are not a registered user on this site.</p>
 <p>Try <a href="individual-level-test.php">logging in</a> again.</p>
 </font>
 </body></center>
 </html>
 <?php
 exit;
 }

 ?>
```

I am using this code for my pages that I need controlled

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['auth']))
   {
     include("admincontrol.php");
   }
  ?>
```

Here is logout.php

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['auth']))
 {
   header("Location: admincontrol.php");
 }

 // Unset all of the session variables.
 $_SESSION = array();

 // If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
 // Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
 if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
  $params = session_get_cookie_params();
  setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
    $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
  );
  }

  // Finally, destroy the session.
  session_destroy();
  ?>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=individual-level-test.php">`
```

Comment: You will benefit from dividing your business script into specialized tasks with either classes or functions. It is more readable and easier to follow the logic that way.

Comment: You should not be using the `mysql_*` series of functions but rather `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Look into prepare/bind to safe-guard against sql injection.

Comment: You should be using password hashing with `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` OR if your php version does not permit those, then a `bcrypt`-compatible library for password verifying and storage.

Comment: Further to my first comment, you should make a series of functions similar to: `is_admin()`, `is_loggedin()`, `log_in_user()`, etc. When you make human-readable functions it will make your script a lot more simple to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have other issues apart from when you're setting the OKAY session variable.

For example:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) 
{ 
    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : $_SESSION['username'];
}
```

You're checking whether the POST value "username" exists and then setting the username variable based on whether the POST value "username" exists with a fallback to the SESSION value "username".

This is redundant code and has the following knock-on effect as follows.

```
if(empty($username)) {}
```

Your username check will always return true for empty() when using this on a secondary page (once you're logged in) and present you with the log on form.

Also your password fallback

```
$pwd = (isset($_POST['pwd']) ? $_POST['pwd'] : (isset($_SESSION['pwd']) ? $_SESSION['pwd'] : 'nopwd'));
$pwd = md5($pwd);
```

Any session password will already be in md5 format, so your database call will fail and present the "Access Denied" screen. Use the md5 function around the $_POST rather than later on in the code to prevent this from happening like this:

```
$pwd = (isset($_POST['pwd']) ? md5($_POST['pwd']) : (isset($_SESSION['pwd']) ? $_SESSION['pwd'] : 'nopwd'));
```

And lastly, you're creating a database call checking the user exists for every time you use admincontrol.php, even once you're logged in on secondary pages. You're storing the user details in SESSION anyway - why have extra db calls when you don't need them.

Comment: Hi Kevan all great stuff!

I replaced if (isset($_POST['username']))  with email as you can't have an account with out on and it now has the desired effect of displaying the Access Denied message. I moved md5() as you suggested. I see that I am calling the database on every page load but I am not sure how to get around this as I need the aid number later in development

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was calling

```
$_SESSION['auth'] = "OKAY";
```

too soon!

It needed to be placed with the other session variables like this

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['pwd'] = $pwd;
$_SESSION['level'] = $level;// 0 = Admin, 1 = institutional subscriber, 2 = individual subscriber
$_SESSION['auth'] = "OKAY";
```